# python: to find the names of students who have a b grade

Tags: python

The following is an excerpt from grades.txt file
Ronald Mayr: A
Bell Kassulke: B
Alexander Zeller: C
Valentina Denk: B
Simon Loidl: B
Elias Jovanovic: B

**I need to list down the names of the students who got B grade.**

First, I tried this

```
import re
def grades():
    with open ("assets/grades.txt", "r") as file:
        grades = file.read()
    title=re.findall("[\w ]*[\(: B\)]",grades)
    funs=(re.split("[\[]",title)[0])
    print(funs)
```

For this, I am getting no output or no error messages, why???
Then, I tried to create a list from the file

```
import re
grades=open("assets/grades.txt")        
lines=[]
for line in grades:
    lines.append(line.strip())
print(lines)
```

Output is
['Ronald Mayr: A', 'Bell Kassulke: B', 'Jacqueline Rupp: A', 'Alexander Zeller: C', 'Valentina Denk: C', 'Simon Loidl: B', 'Elias Jovanovic: B', 'Stefanie Weninger: A', 'Fabian Peer: C', 'Hakim Botros: B', 'Emilie Lorentsen: B', 'Herman Karlsen: C', 'Nathalie Delacruz: C', 'Casey Hartman: C', 'Lily Walker : A', 'Gerard Wang: C', 'Tony Mcdowell: C', 'Jake Wood: B', 'Fatemeh Akhtar: B', 'Kim Weston: B', 'Nicholas Beatty: A', 'Kirsten Williams: C', 'Vaishali Surana: C', 'Coby Mccormack: C', 'Yasmin Dar: B', 'Romy Donnelly: A', 'Viswamitra Upandhye: B', 'Kendrick Hilpert: A', 'Killian Kaufman: B', 'Elwood Page: B', 'Mukti Patel: A', 'Emily Lesch: C', 'Elodie Booker: B', 'Jedd Kim: A', 'Annabel Davies: A', 'Adnan Chen: B', 'Jonathan Berg: C', 'Hank Spinka: B', 'Agnes Schneider: C', 'Kimberly Green: A', 'Lola-Rose Coates: C', 'Rose Christiansen: C', 'Shirley Hintz: C', 'Hannah Bayer: B']

Q1) Is this step, to convert the text file to strings, needed in order to reach the final purpose. If so,to get the above output, what should I do if I need to mandatorily have to retain the following lines.

```
import re
def grades():
    with open ("assets/grades.txt", "r") as file:
        grades = file.read()
```

Then I tried to find the names before ': B' pattern using

```
title=re.findall("[\w ]*[\(: B\)]",grades)
    funs=(re.split("[\[]",title)[0])
    return(funs)
```

**Following error occurs**

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-44948aa27939> in <module>
      6     funs=(re.split("[\[]",title)[-2:])
      7     return(funs)
----> 8 assert len(grades()) == 16
      9 

<ipython-input-6-44948aa27939> in grades()
      4         grades = file.read()
      5     title=re.findall("[\w ]*[\(: B\)]",grades)
----> 6     funs=(re.split("[\[]",title)[-2:])
      7     return(funs)
      8 assert len(grades()) == 16

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/re.py in split(pattern, string, maxsplit, flags)
    211     and the remainder of the string is returned as the final element
    212     of the list."""
--> 213     return _compile(pattern, flags).split(string, maxsplit)
    214 
    215 def findall(pattern, string, flags=0):

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Q3) How to solve this

Comment: Does the input file have one name and a grade per line or is it really as you've shown - i.e., no line breaks?

Answer (score 0):

If your input file has no line breaks then you don't really need *re* for this - just a simple loop as follows:

```
from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(list)

with open('grades.txt', encoding='utf-8') as data:
    name = []
    tokens = data.read().split()
    i = 0
    while i < len(tokens):
        token = tokens[i]
        if token[-1] == ':':
            name.append(token[:-1])
            i += 1
            result[tokens[i]].append(' '.join(name))
            name = []
        else:
            name.append(token)
        i += 1
print(result['B'])
```

Comment: Thanks Olvin, it works. But it would be great if you can convey what was wrong with the syntax I created